# Please advise which case I am not covering

Tags: c, geometry, rectangles, area, cartesian-coordinates

> - Given 2 rectangles parallel to coordinate axes, find the area covered by them.

**Input Format:**
First line of input contains T - number of test cases. Its followed by 2T lines. First line of each test case contains 4 integers - xbl, ybl, xtr, ytr - the bottom-left and top-right coordinates of rectangle-1. The second line of each test case contains 4 integers - xbl, ybl, xtr, ytr - the bottom-left and top-right coordinates of rectangle-2.

Constraints

- 1 <= T <= 10000
- -10<sup>6</sup> < x,y <= 10<sup>6</sup>
- (xbl, ybl) < (xtr, ytr)

**Output Format:**
 For each test case, print the area covered by the 2 rectangles, separated by newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int recarea(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){
    int area=0;
    area=(x2-x1)*(y2-y1);
    return abs(area);
}

unsigned int overarea(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3,int x4,int y4){
    int top=fmin(y2,y4);
    int bottom=fmax(y1,y3);
    int left=fmax(x1,x3);
    int right=fmin(x2,x4);
    int overlaparea=0;
    if(bottom<top && left<right){
        overlaparea=recarea(left,bottom,right,top);
    }
    return abs(overlaparea);
}

int main() {
    int testcases=0;
    scanf("%d",&testcases);
    for(int i=0;i<testcases;i++){
        int x1,x2,y1,y2,x3,x4,y3,y4;
        scanf("%d %d %d %d",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
        scanf("%d %d %d %d",&x3,&y3,&x4,&y4);
        int area=recarea(x1,y1,x2,y2)+recarea(x3,y3,x4,y4)- 
         overarea(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);
        printf("%d\n",area);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

The variables x1, y1 are bottom left coordinates and x2, y2 are top right 
           coordinates for Rectangle 1.
           The variables x3, y3 are bottom left coordinates and x4, y4 are top right 
           coordinates for Rectangle 2.

Comment: Do you have a test case that is failing? Have you run that case in the debugger to see why?

Comment: Hi Retired Ninja. The test case is hidden. Every thing seems to be perfect for me.

Comment: Are you failing all test cases or just some test cases?

Comment: only 1 test case.

Comment: -10^6 < x and y < 10^ 6

Comment: You probably just need to test some more boundary cases. What if both rectangles are identical?

Comment: If `x1 = -99999, y1 = -99999, x2 = 99999, y2 = 99999` then your code will overflow the size of a 32-bit `int`. If that's the case then you should use an `int64_t`.

Comment: @user218324 If values can go up to 10^6 (as said in comment, but different from the question), then you might have integer overflow.

Comment: Thank you all, I will check. these cases.

Comment: Which cases do you think you *have* covered?  The two rectangles could have no overlap at all; one rectangle could be completely inside the other (or the two rectangles could be exactly the same); or the two rectangles could partially overlap.  Have you handled all three of those?

Comment: @Jonathan, the code handles those cases. I modified slightly to handle the overflow and also to handle case when both the Rectangles are same. It passed all the cases now.

Comment: Why oh why use `x1,y1,x2,y2` to represent `xbl, ybl, xtr, ytr`?

Answer (score 0):

> Please advise which case I am not covering

**Use wider math**

`area=(x2-x1)*(y2-y1);` is prone to `int` overflow given -10<sup>6</sup> < x,y <= 10<sup>6</sup>.

The max area is about 4*10<sup>12</sup>, outside the range of most `int` implementions (32 or 16 bit).

`long long` covers *at least* the range -(2<sup>63</sup> + 1) ... +(2<sup>63</sup> + 1)

```
long long recarea(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    long long area = (0LL + x2 - x1)*(0LL + y2 - y1);
    return llabs(area);
}

   long long area = recarea(...
   printf("%lld\n",area);
```

Adjust `overarea()` too.

**Other**

Other functional problems may exist.  Example: `int` may be as small as 16-bit.  Consider using `long` instead to handle -10<sup>6</sup> < x,y <= 10<sup>6</sup>.

---

**Aside**

Code is using floating point functions with `fmin(), fmax()`.  I'd used a integer only approach rather than incur various problems switching between FP and integer.  Looks OK here given the small range, but not for larger values.